# Why did I get +1 Reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

On my [profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20752/kevdog777), under the reputation frame, I see that I earned +1 reputation. I thought the minimum is +2 reputation.

Please could someone explain this to me?

Comment: at 1000+ rep you can click on the number of votes (to the left of a Q or A, between the up and down arrows) and see the seperate up and down votes http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, looking at the reputation tab, sorted by time, I can see:

```
+5   21:02  upvote
-2   16:02  downvote
-2   16:00  downvote
```

So that is where I got the +1 rep from.

Comment: You can also get +1's if you DV a A, and the answer is deleted.